# Asset loading from another directory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to figure out the following dilemma.

**Example:**

Visiting url: http://localhost/admin/content/1/builder
Iframe URL (on page): http://localhost/templates/silver-1/index.html

Now inside the index.html an asset will be requested like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
```

I'm ofcourse unable to use {{ asset('css/site.css') }} because this is a .html file which will be used for a page builder which later gets "compiled" to a blade.php file.

Instead of replacing all the asset urls when I "compile" the page I want to redirect them if they get requested in this manner:

http://localhost/1/css/site.css > http://localhost/templates/silver-1/css/site.css
http://localhost/1/some_sub_dir/css/site.css > http://localhost/templates/silver-1/css/site.css

Now I did a ***Nasty*** work-around by using the following route:

```
Route::get('/{id}/{dir?}/{path?}', function($id, $dir = null, $path = null) {
    $page = Session::get('Site.current.page');
    $location = Session::get('Site.current.template_location');

    if(!$page || $page != $id) {
        if(is_numeric($id)) {
            $page = Frontend\Models\Page::find($id);
            $location = $page->template->template_location;
            Session::put('Site.current.page', $page->id);
            Session::put('Site.current.template_location', $location);
        }
    }

    $p = plugin_path('Frontend', sprintf('templates/%s/%s/%s', $location, $dir, $path));

    if(!file_exists($p)) {
        return null;
    }

    return Redirect::to(plugin_asset('Frontend', sprintf('templates/%s/%s/%s', $location, $dir, $path)));
})
->where('id', '[0-9]')
->where('dir', 'js|css|img|font|vendors|stylesheets|images|assets|js-files')
->where('path', '(.*)');
```

Now please excuse me, as I myself find that code horrible, broken and garbage, hence why I'm looking for a better way to solve it either with .htaccess or something else...

I've tried combining redirect statements inside the laravel .htaccess which is as followed:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

No matter what I do with the .htaccess I either wind up breaking it (500 / laravel routing borked)

Any help is greatly appreciated, if more code or explanation is required please comment below.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^css yoursubfolder/css [QSA,NC]
```

Basically you can redirect it to any path you like

You should also call your css folder like /css/site.css so it will try to get the root css folder

Comment: I'm really terrible with htaccess configurations, where would I put this in the htaccess I showed above?

Comment: Where your rewriterules are you can try also to manipulate it for your own needs

Comment: Can't get it working with my current setup. It doesn't redirect the url.

Comment: See my edit, this allows you to call /css/site.css and actually put you css files in a subfolder